# Application.Screenupdating = false affects all of office

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a model built in excel that I need to keep running for my dissertation. To help speed it up I've put in `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` however this is also affecting Word which means I can't do any other work.

Is there any way of fixing this so I can work in Word while Excel is running?

Comment: How long does the macro run for? Have you included `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at at the end of the procedure?

Comment: It's running the model over an over again or so hence it can be running for multiple hours at a time. I have included `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end when a set of runs has concluded and the screen returns to normal

Comment: Does it still occur with using `Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating`?